# How to check if "should has text" in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, functional-testing, end-to-end

I need to do something like:

```
expect(theElement.hasText()).toBe(true);
```

Do you know how can I do it?

I know that there is a "getText" function in protractor, but, how can I use it?
Should I do?:

```
expect(theElement.getText().lenght > 0).toBe(true);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find [`jasmine-matchers`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers) library very helpful in terms of additional useful matchers. `toBeNonEmptyString()` is a perfect fit here (also notice how readable it is):

```
expect(theElement.getText()).toBeNonEmptyString();
```

FYI, here is the [underlying implementation](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers/blob/8956604ec08a3b5d2908b7c44eaca13c9a7e3c0b/src/strings.js#L21):

```
matchers.toBeNonEmptyString = function() {
  return matchers.toBeString.call(this) &&
    this.actual.length > 0;
};
```

It is quite reliable: *it checks the type and the length*.

Comment: It was... soooo beautiful! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check length and don't want to use toBeNonEmpty, then check it in the callback

```
element(by.id('element_id')).getText().then(function (data) {
  expect(data.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
});
```